# Problem with Springer cropS.sty style

Tags: crop, pdfcrop

I am now making a translated version of the book: Proofs from THE BOOK. I have finished the chapters, but when I put it into the common file to compile, the **cropS** package crops the page as in the MWE.

The problem is, I'm working on the file that the author shared, and I have no problem with the original file from the author.

Here is a MWE

```
\documentclass[10pt,springer]{PFTB}        
\usepackage[cam,a4,center]{cropS}
%\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T5]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{Proofs}
\usepackage{mac,makeidx,oldgerm,paralist,url}
\def\UrlFont{\rm}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,mathtools}
\usepackage[]{graphicx} 
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\author{{\sffamily\LARGE Martin Aigner \qquad G\"unter M. Ziegler}\\[3mm]
{\sffamily\Large Illustrate by Karl Heinrich Hofmann}}
\title{{\sffamily\bfseries\Huge Proofs from THE BOOK}}
\date{{\sffamily\Large Springer-Verlag Heidelberg/Berlin\\[3mm] 
Fifth Edition, 2014}}%

\maketitle

\pagenumbering{Roman}
\setcounter{page}{5}%

\lipsum 
\clearpage
\lhead[\fancyplain{\headlinerule}{\thepage}
]{\fancyplain{\headlinerule}{\itshape\rightmark}}

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\lipsum 
\end{document}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: It is good to post code but this is, frankly, not useful. It cannot be used to reproduce the issue you need help with since we have neither the class `PFTB.cls` nor the package `cropS.sty`. Since the latter is, according to your account, an essential part of the problem, you probably need to tell us where we can find the package. If the problem can be reproduced with a standard class, use that for your MWE. Otherwise, if the class is also crucial, you also need to tell us where we can find that.

Comment: Thank @cfr. I wonder whether uploading PFTB.cls and cropS.sty is not preserved the copyrigjht?

Comment: That you would have to check. If they are publicly accessible, you can provide links. If not, you'd need to check the licence. But we are going to need enough information in some form to reproduce the problem. If you can't reproduce it without code you can't share, then all we can say is that the problem is somewhere in that code. If you can reproduce without code you can't share, then just tell us how to reproduce the issue. You may not be able to provide sufficient information for us to help. That is a problem with proprietary code, unfortunately.